# Mobile hotspot missing on iphone 4

Tags: tethering

I updated to the new IOS 7 and it took my mobile hotspot option off the menu settings. Not sure what to do any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are you on a [carrier that is officially supported](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1937) by Apple, your need a mobile contract that allows Personal Hotspot, otherwise it will not work. If your carrier allows it, update your *Carrier Settings*:

- Make sure internet works
- Settings > General > About
- You will see a popup to inform you of the update.

If you are on an unofficial carrier, you should configure Personal Hotspot manually:

- Settings > Cellular > Cellular Data Network
- Scroll to the bottom, under Personal Hotspot, enter the APN, Username and Password you received from your carrier.

If any of the above options are missing, it means that your carrier has disabled them.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to find the hotspot menu under Settings > Cellular > Hotspot.
Source: [iOS: Understanding Personal Hotspot](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4517)